# trying to hide and show a div on mouseenter and mouse leave

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide and show a div when mouseenter and mouseleave. i was trying like this

jQuery

```
$("#container-advanced-option").stop().fadeToggle(100, "linear", function () {
    $("#keyword-inventory-widget").on("mouseenter mouseleave #container-advanced-option", function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).parents('#keyword-inventory-widget').length === 0) {
            $('#container-advanced-option').fadeToggle(100);
            $("#keyword-inventory-widget").off("#container-advanced-option");
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="keyword-inventory-widget" class="black-layer clearfix">
     <h3>SEARCH </h3>

    <input id="iks-input-keyword-main" class="form-control t-margin-5 pull-left" placeholder="Search for Vehicle (eg blue 2015 Tahoe)" style="width: 80%" />
    <button id="iks-search-default" class="btn btn-green t-margin-5 pull-right" style="width: 19%">SEARCH</button>
    <div id="container-advanced-option" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h5 class="b-margin">Advance Search Options</h5>
            <select id="iks-miles" class="form-control">
                <option value="30">30 Miles</option>
                <option value="50">50 Miles</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button id="iks-search-advanced" class="btn btn-green t-margin-5 pull-left">SEARCH</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

that's my summary of code look like

**updated**
**

> my requirement is show "container-advanced-option" on
>   keyword-inventory-widget mouse over and stay focused until i leave the
>   keyword-inventory-widget div.

**

http://jsfiddle.net/9eSKg/

Comment: where you want to hover and what you want to show/hide

Comment: Your jsFiddle needs jQuery library to be loaded (as-is, it simply fails to do anything). See http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/9eSKg/3/

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this.

[**Demo Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/49GkJ/1/)

**JS Code**

```
 $("#hoverDiv").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#hiddenDiv").slideDown();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $("#hiddenDiv").slideUp();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="hoverDiv">hover on me</div>
<div id="hiddenDiv">show/hide div</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#hiddenDiv{display:none;}
```

Comment: not exactly but i have updated the JSfiddle code. when i try to focus select it won't work as i expected.. Thanks
http://jsfiddle.net/49GkJ/3/

Answer (score 0):

Why not use CSS? Use `.your_div:hover{visibility:hidden;}`

Comment: i need some animation as well.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I usually end up with something like this...

```
$(function() 
  {
      $('#container-advanced-option').hide();

      $('#keyword-inventory-widget').hover(function() {
          $('#container-advanced-option')
          .stop()
          .animate(
              {
                  height: 'toggle'
              },
              {
                  duration: 100,
                  easing: 'linear' // Use easing plugin for more effects
              }
          );
      });
  }
 );
```

I am not saying this is the only way to add effects on hover event but it works with your code just fine (try it out in your fiddle).. hope it helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help but it won't fix my issue as when i try to use dropdown it getting hide

Comment: By dropdown do you mean the select box options?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle... moving the closing div tag so that it contains the toggled content helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/49GkJ/5/

html

```
<div id="hoverDiv">hover on me
  <div id="hiddenDiv">
    <select id="iks-miles" class="form-control">
        <option value="30">30 Miles</option>
        <option value="50">50 Miles</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$("#hoverDiv").hover(function () {
  $("#hiddenDiv").slideToggle();
});
```

css

```
#hiddenDiv {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply i need to stay on focus until i leave main div  could you please check the updated post .. thanks